# How to get number of rows in a SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get number of rows with a SQL query?

I tried this :

```
SET @Records = count(*) SELECT * FROM  [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS] 
                WHERE Field_Tag = '1234'
```

But it is giving 1. What is wrong with the above code?

Actually there was no row, it should give the output 0

When I execute this

```
SELECT * FROM  [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS] 
WHERE Field_Tag = '1234'
```

it is giving result 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SET @Records = (SELECT count(*)
                  FROM [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS]
                 WHERE Field_Tag = '1234')
```

Comment: @nirudyogi, did you try to enclose with brackets? Ah, yeah, codingbiz said it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @Records = COUNT(*) FROM INVENTORY.TBL_RECEIPTS
   WHERE Field_Tag = '1234';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do these - either should work, but I prefer the second code

```
SET @Records = (SELECT Count(*) FROM  [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS] 
                WHERE Field_Tag = '1234')
```

OR

```
SELECT @Records = Count(*) FROM  [INVENTORY].[TBL_RECEIPTS] 
                WHERE Field_Tag = '1234'
```